# Is there a way to compare jenkins console outputs?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Is there a way to compare current console output with a saved console output from a previous run in jenkins on a free style job? Looking to compare if the same files have been built on the current run vs the previous run.

I looked into console parser and log parser plugins but did not see a way to pass in the saved console output to compare the current console output.

Thanks!

Comment: save them into text file and beyond compare??

Comment: thanks @Han.Oliver but that will not set the build result to success and failure per the results. That will be manual process, wanted it to be part of the free style job. I will look into if beyond compare is compatible with jenkins.

Comment: you probably only want the log of a single command? You could write/pipe that to a file, archive that file and then use copy artifact. Otherwise you would have to look into the folder structure and find the location of the old log file. Alternativly there might by an internal method for this